# Chrome Developer tools css editing

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools, code-assist, cssedit

I use Chrome developer tools and trying to edit css from resources but couldn't figure out how to "enable coding assist". When I type "disp" in console, I wanna see all available properties. Is there a way to enable this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is not the exact answer to your question, but the way you can do it is:
Go to Elements and see your css on the right and edit it there. Type i.e. "display", press TAB and then on the value-side of display press CTRL + SPACE. With the arrow keys up and down you will have a live preview in the DOM to see, how your settings are affecting it.
See this:
[image: Chrome Dev Tools Elements - View]